# How to select input date as default in JQuery datepicker?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, datepicker

I have an ASP.NET application which uses JQuery datepicker for picking dates in some text boxes. For some date textboxes, I populate the date textbox from my database. When this textbox is clicked my JQuery datepicker appears, and it shows the current month with Today highlighted. This is fine for empty textboxes, however sometimes the text box is populated from the database.

When the textbox is not empty I want the datepicker to show the textbox month and have the selected date to be the textbox date.

Is this possible?

Here's my current javascript code in my asp.net script header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTextBox').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            autoSize: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            maxDate: 0
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the format of your datepicker matches the format output by your serverside code. If they're exactly the same then it'll work. It won't try to parse the date if it's in a different format though.

Comment: That's OK. I had exactly the same issue with a Rails app recently. It's a pain, because the app can take any number of date formats, but the datepicker is really ... picky.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `defaultDate`. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTextBox').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            autoSize: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            maxDate: 0,
            defaultDate: new Date()
        });
    });  
</script>
```

This will initialize the default date to today's date. You need to add server side code that will initialize `defaultDate` to whatever you want.